# Inner join update set postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

So I want to make the product between the sum of the number of days that a prisoner has worked and the multiplication coefficient for the specific task.
I tried this code:

```
UPDATE prisoners
    SET nr_days_equaled = (SELECT COALESCE (multiplication_coefficient*SUM(nr_days_worked),0)
                           FROM prisoners pr 
                              INNER JOIN timesheets_prisoners tp ON pr.idprisoner= tp.idprisoner 
                              INNER JOIN nomenclature_activities_prisoners nap ON pp.idactivity=nap.idactivity)
```

But I get the following error:

> column "nap.multiplication_coefficient" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

What can I do? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you realize that your current `UPDATE` will update _every_ record in the `prisoners` table?  Is this what you intended?

Comment: if using SUM then its assumed you would be using some kind of aggregation

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to update all rows in nr_days_equaled but with a specific value for every prisoner that worked in prison, that will result from the calculation above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

When using any aggregate function (SUM, COUNT, MIN MAX etc.) together with any other field in your select statement, you must GROUP By the other fields selected.  So in your case the compiler wants:

```
UPDATE prisoners
SET nr_days_equaled = 
(SELECT COALESCE (multiplication_coefficient*SUM(nr_days_worked),0)
FROM prisoners pr INNER JOIN timesheets_prisoners tp 
ON pr.idprisoner= tp.idprisoner 
INNER JOIN nomenclature_activities_prisoners nap 
ON pp.idactivity=nap.idactivity GROUP BY multiplication_coefficient)
```

However, without seeing the inner structure of your tables, I suspect that this is not really what you want.  My suspicion is that you really need

```
SET nr_days_equaled = 
(SELECT COALESCE (SUM(multiplication_coefficient*nr_days_worked),0)
FROM prisoners pr INNER JOIN timesheets_prisoners tp 
ON pr.idprisoner= tp.idprisoner 
INNER JOIN nomenclature_activities_prisoners nap 
ON pp.idactivity=nap.idactivity)
```

The difference is that this version allows for different multiplication_coefficients for different work, but still sums the total.  I stress that I am not sure.  Please test by converting this to a SELECT statement before issuing the UPDATE.

EDIT

Having seen the structure, what you need is:

```
UPDATE prisoners
SET nr_days_equaled = SubQ.sumdaysmult
FROM
(SELECT pr.idprisoner, COALESCE (ppnap.sumdaysmult, 0) AS sumdaysmult FROM 
FROM prisoners pr LEFT JOIN (SELECT tp.idprisoner, SUM(tp.nr_days_worked
* nap.multiplication_coefficient) as sumdaysmult
FROM timesheets_prisoners tp 
INNER JOIN nomenclature_activities_prisoners nap 
ON tp.idactivity=nap.idactivity GROUP BY tp.idprisoner) tpnap
ON tpnap.idprisoner = pr.idprisoner) AS SubQ
WHERE SubQ.idprisoner = prisoners.idprisoner
```

Comment: This works somehow. But what I need is to group what activities  every prisoner has done and do those calculations. Because my code now populates every row with the same value. If I try to GROUP BY idprisoner it gives my the error that idprisoner is too ambigous.

Comment: To help more, I'd really need to see the full table structure

Comment: Sorry wasn't concentrating.  Yes you probably do need to GROUP BY idprisoner.  Postgres complains about ambiguity because idprisoner is in more than one table in the join.  To get around this GROUP By one of them, for example GROUP BY pr.idprisoner.  It doesn't matter whether you take pr or tp since idprisoner is the same value.

Comment: I tried that but I get another error : more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

Comment: Sorry to fix this for you, I really do need to see the structure.  Your update needs to update by prisonerid, so the SELECT has to contain it and join to it. If you do not want to post the structure here, you can always email me privately.  My email is on the Contact page of my WebSite (which is shown on my profile).

Comment: I sent it to you on e-mail.

Comment: Sorry nothing received - please try jwillcock19@gmail.com instead??

Comment: I send it again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use group by using nap.multiplication_coefficient